# How to increase text size systemwide including browsers ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, screen, display-resolution

I have a new laptop which is 1920x1080 width(15') . The thing is text size in display is very small which puts a strain on my eyes. I changed the text size inside ubuntu through system settings-> displays , but the browsers(mozilla,google-chrome) still displays very small text and there is a wide empty space on both side when I am browsing. How can I fix this ?

Comment: how you change the "text size inside ubuntu through system settings-> displays " do you mean resolution ???

Comment: if you need to change the text size download tweak tool and the open it  on **appearance ->  fonts**

Comment: I just set the default zoom on both browsers to be ~150%.

Comment: nope , U used scaling scaling

Comment: Settings => Accessibility => Large Text (toggle)

Answer (score 3):

> but the browsers(mozilla,google-chrome) still displays very small text and there is a wide empty space on both side when I am browsing. How can I fix this ?

Browsers use their own fonts.

You can increase font size on browsers with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and decrease it with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

- You can also change this in Chrome, options, content, fonts&colors.
- Firefox, settings, webcontent.

Comment: I want everything to be a little larger , not only fonts , but also icons ,is that possible

Comment: Control+ does not do that?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to use **Universal Access** settings and toggle the larger text option.
[image]

I actually found this by hitting WinKey and typing font:

[image]

This will increase the font size for everything and tell all your applications to do so too. Some apps need to be closed and reopened before they will listen but others will instantly respond.

Now, this only scales the fronts 25% bigger. If that is not enough you can manually set this value with the Gnome Tweak Tool.

Here's an install guide I found:
https://linuxhint.com/gnome_tweak_installation_ubuntu/
You want this any for many other customizations.

Once installed you can adjust the text scaling factor used by the accessibility feature. Hit WinKey type "tweak" and choose the Tweaks icon.

Under fonts, change the scaling factor. (don't change the actual font sizes tho).
[image]
I set mine to 1.75.

**PS -**
Alternatively, you can actually set the UI scaling in display settings instead and this will scale everything up not just the text. This is the better option but may run a bit slower on low powered graphics.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem solved by the next.
Go to APPLICATION STYLE then to GNOME APPLICATION STYLE (GTK) then to FONTS (CHOOSE) and set it bolder and bigger